# Restricting VMware View Copy/Paste Functionality

Tags: data-leakage, vmware

Does anybody know if it's possible to restrict VMware View copy/paste functionality depending on the source of the client?

It seems VDIs can have GPOs set to configure copy/paste functionality, but we have some users accessing VDIs from internal systems where we'd like to enable copy/paste in and out of VDIs. But we also have some users accessing VDIs remotely where we'd like to fully disable copy/paste to mitigate malware and data loss risks.

VMware does allow VMware View Security servers so potentially different view servers would be used to distinguish internal from external users. But if the control is applied by GPO, that doesn't help. Surely I'm not the only person to have this type of requirement?

Any help would be most appreciated!